# Finding a particular solution to a given pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given This PDE:
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} - c^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = \epsilon e^{-t/\tau} \delta(x), \quad \tau > 0,$$
How can I find the particular solution?

The boundary conditions are: $u(x=-L,t)=u(x=L,t)=0$, where
$L, c$ and $\epsilon$ are given parameters.

Comment: Step 1: Read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Step 2: Ask a good question.  That includes formatting of formulas using mathjax, and (important) include what you have done so far.

Comment: [Duhamel's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duhamel%27s_principle#Wave_equation)

Comment: @Winther Which part? Wave equation? If so, are the boundary conditions the same? If not, which part please?